# Splash screen animation loops on start

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I have a simple splash screen animation activity i added `postDelayed()` to pass intent start activity, but i find a loop in animation [here is a video displaying the loop](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19W8amk0ieQIfzzPMWZY73SI955TJ7H7f/view?usp=sharing)

code :

```
   public class loadingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    Animation topAnimation, bottomAnimation, middleAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        topAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loadingScreen.this, R.anim.slide_down);
        bottomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loadingScreen.this,R.anim.bottom_up);
        middleAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(loadingScreen.this,R.anim.fade_in2);

        final ImageView image1 = findViewById(R.id.image1);
        final ImageView image2 = findViewById(R.id.image2);
        final ImageView image3 = findViewById(R.id.image3);
        final ImageView image4 = findViewById(R.id.image4);
        final ImageView image5 = findViewById(R.id.image5);
        final ImageView image6 = findViewById(R.id.image6);
        final TextView text1 = findViewById(R.id.app_title);
        final TextView text2 = findViewById(R.id.app_desc);

        text1.setAnimation(middleAnimation);
        text2.setAnimation(middleAnimation);

        image1.setAnimation(topAnimation);
        image2.setAnimation(topAnimation);
        image3.setAnimation(topAnimation);

        image4.setAnimation(bottomAnimation);
        image5.setAnimation(bottomAnimation);
        image6.setAnimation(bottomAnimation);

        int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1500;
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(loadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Am not sure why i get a loop on animation ending.

**Where Else if i try a app with `splashScreen` with empty `Main activity`, i don't see the loop at end.**

Comment: https://androidapps-development-blogs.medium.com/android-splash-screen-animated-splash-screen-shared-animation-splash-screen-android-studio-17a4ec07d7a0

Comment: do not repeat your animation as its animation time is less than splash timeout.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i was following the exact tutorial. If you could watch this video you can understand the issue am facing https://drive.google.com/file/d/19W8amk0ieQIfzzPMWZY73SI955TJ7H7f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari so what am i doing wrong ? and what should i do ?

Comment: @sanojlawrence in your animation XML files set  `android:repeatCount="once"`

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari yes i tried still the same issue